# Dropdown menu code needed for web versions

Tags: html, css, mobile

I have a site where in the top header area I have a dropdown which only works when the user hovers the mouse over it (http://liquor.com). But in mobile versions I've been informed this behaviour won't work.

So I'll put a conditional statement in the code and display another dropdown menu, but I'm curious what code should be used for a mobile dropdown.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not an answer, but some related thoughts: http://www.cennydd.co.uk/2010/end-hover-abuse-now/

Comment: interesting the twitter worm populated via hovers. too bad the website owners wanted hover effect :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this: http://css-tricks.com/unobtrusive-page-changer/

Answer (score 1):

I have pure CSS (no javascript at all) 2-level drop-down menus that work on at least the iPod touch, iPhone, and iPad.

All that was required was to add a dummy `onclick` handler, so

```
<li><div class="menuheader">Reports</div>
... </li>
```

became

```
<li><div class="menuheader" onclick="void(0)">Reports</div>
... </li>
```

This was described in Apple's [Safari Reference Library](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/navigation/) entry for [Making Elements Clickable](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html).

Answer (score 0):

Because mobile platforms cannot :hover, you have to bind the dropdown menu to click events instead.

Basically follow this procedure to create a dropdown menu:

- Capture the click event for top-row navigation links (because users cannot hover)
- Prevent default (browser loading new page)
- Load appropriate submenu depending on which top-nav link was clicked.
- Remove submenu when it loses focus (user clicks on page or other top-nav-link)